# How would I create code to install my app from the url bar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, when I went to https://chromestatus.com/features I noticed in the url bar app it said install app. When I clicked it it install a chrome web app with the website in it. How would I be able to implement this in my website?

I tried going through the source code of the website and didn't find anything useful.
When you hover over it says install. It is the button right next to the bookmark. I don't know if this is an experimental feature since I'm on chrome canary. But I still want to implement it into my website. Is it possible to do it with java script?
[image: Url bar]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) and Chrome is testing the plus button UI for the [add to homescreen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) behaviour.

To do this for your website you'd need a web app manifest and a service worker. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) for more info.